# Quickly find out which Git remote is being tracked in VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, branch, git-branch, git-remote

I often use two Git remotes--both with their own `master` branches--with some of my projects.

Bad practice aside, is there a way to quickly identify which `<remote>/master` is currently being tracked by local checked-out branch in VS Code?

I'm looking for a better visual cue, ideally something that displays this information in the status bar or in the Source Control pane.

[image: source_control_vscode]

Currently, I either need to perform a `git branch -avv` from the command line, or I need to look at GitLens or Git Graph to reveal this information.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Your posted image is unreadable. Please pose the output of `git branch -avv`.

Comment: Remotes don't get "checked out". That phrase is meaningless and confusing. If you're asking how to check which branch your local `master` is tracking, please ask _that_.

Comment: Fixed the thumbnail image and clarified my question. Thanks

Comment: Does the "Show Repository Status" I mention below answer your question?

Comment: It does and that is helpful. Crazy how I missed that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitLens has a [Show Repository Status](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens#repository-status) command which will tell you is your are ahead/behind of the remote/branch currently being tracked by the checked out branch:

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/master/images/docs/menu-repo-status.png]

Here the current remote is `origin`, and the branch is tracking the `origin/demo` branch.